# how to handle dynamic import for a const value using top level await method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am trying to use a const files import based on the envrionment using dynamic import. When I use await method in toplevel to export a const value i am getting error as "cannot use keyword await outside of async method". Anything i am doing wrong here?

```
export const urls = await import(`./environments/${environment}`)
```

[image]

Comment: What part of the error message do you not understand?  You apparently have an environment that does not yet support top level await.

Answer (score 1):

For platforms that do not yet support [top-level await](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-top-level-await) you will need to wrap your import and code into an async function:

```js
async function main() {
  const urls = await import(`./environments/${environment}`)
  // do work
}
main()
```

What you can do is also export the promise:

```js
let promise;
let result = {};
async function main() {
  promise = import(`./environments/${environment}`);
  result.urls = await promise;
}
main()
export { ready, result }
```

So consuming modules can also await the value, or check if the value is ready